# Typeahead not working when first letter typed

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

In my java script, i try to display typeahead. It won't display the countries typing first letter, but it displays when iam typing second letter.

my script is

```
 $('#country_v1-query').typeahead({
            order: "desc",            
            source: {
                data: [
                    "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Andorra", "Angola",  "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom", "United States",  "Uruguay", "Uzbekistan", "Vanuatu", "Venezuela", "Vietnam", "Yemen", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"
                ]
            },
            callback: {
                onInit: function (node) {
                    console.log('Typeahead Initiated on ' + node.selector);
                }
            }
        });
```

and i call the script using id like this

```
 <input type="text" id="country_v1-query" name="country_v1[query]" autocomplete="on" class=" typeahead" data-provide="typeahead"  />
```

the including links are
`typeahead.js, typeahead.css, jquery-ui.js, jquery-ui.css, bootstrap.min.css`

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, i insert `minLength: "1",` in my script it works.